# Second Select in Joomla 1.5 custom component

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have developed custom component.. Initially Joomla 1.5 has data array that sends data from the table to the template.

```
class MyComponentClass extends JModel{

    /**
     * MyComponentClass data array for tmp store
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $_data;
    /**
     * MyComponentClass data array for tmp store
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $_mine;

    /**
     * Gets the data
     * @return mixed The data to be displayed to the user
     */
    public function getData(){
        if (empty( $this->_data )){
            $id = JRequest::getInt('id',  0);
            $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__tourinfo` where `id` = {$id}";
            $db->setQuery( $query );
            $this->_data = $db->loadObject();
        }
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function getMine(){
        if (empty( $this->_mine )){
            $recordSet =& $this->getTable('mytable');
            $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM `#__mytable` WHERE ' . (isset($recordSet->published)?'`published`':'1') . ' = 1 ORDER BY `id` ';
            $this->_mine = $this->_getList( $query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit') );
        }   
        return $this->_mine;
    }   

}
```

according to documentation I have seen only $_data array that sends info to the template.

This model sends data for the single record view.

In other table I have some data that is associated with this record.

When I try to receive data into the template, I have an error that no data is supplied to foreach.

Probably someone knows the solution  for this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You assign any data that the template needs in your yourcomponent/view/yourview/view.html.php file.

Please see:

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Here's an example of a typical method in a view.html.php file:

```
function listItems()
{
    $model = &$this->getModel('yourmodel');
    $items = $model->getItems();
    if ($items) {
            $this->assignRef( 'items', $items );
    }

    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

Notice the assignment in the code above:

$this->assignRef( 'items', $items );

You can then call $this->items in your template to loop through with your foreach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thatnks seavers for the answer.. actually it worked, the code that I wrote above.. I did't mean having extra view page, I wanted to have that data coming into this view page.
And i had just an type error. So the code published above is correct. But thanks!!!